# include header file or not

Tags: c, header-files

In the header file (`funlist.h`), I listed all the function prototypes such as:

`int sum(int a,int b);`

`float prod(float c,float d);`

After that, when I define what "sum" and "prod" are in one C source file (`operator.c`), do I have to `#include "funlist.h"` at the beginning?

I compiled and found both include or not include can get the right result. I'm confused why and looking forward to having a explanation.

Comment: Welcome. Have a look at [What's the benefit for a C source file include its own header file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30817570/3258851). Also, I'd advise to use the same name for both the header file and implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice.

For a more solid reason than that though: If one of your functions calls another defined in `operator.c` you need to make sure that either a declaration or a definition for that function occurs *before* the call to it. The best way to do *that* is to declare all of you functions before you define any. And since the header file is nothing but those declarations, it makes sense to `#include` it to ensure everything is there.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, when I call the functions "sum" or "prod" in the `main.c` code, I truly `#include "funlist.h"` at the beginning. As I said, I declared "sum" or "prod" in `funlist.h` and defined them in `operatior.c`, and I tried not to `#include "funlist.h"` in the `operatior.c` because in reality I have hundreds more `operatior.c` that define the function declared in `funlist.h`. And it worked. But, as you said, it's better include the header file in `operatior.c` such that the code looks more professional, am I right?